# Import jquery and bootstrap in to nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a bootstrap template and I wanna import to nuxtjs project but I got an error for bootstrap
and jquery files and during rendering, I got error 404
please help me?

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error for bootstrap and jquery files

So if I understand that correctly you are getting an error message that says that something is not right with the mentioned-above files?
I don't know exactly what you have tried already, but you should be aware that bootstrap uses internal CSS and Js resources as well as jquery and popper in their templates, so you will have to download all of those and fix all the source references for the templates to work properly. If it cannot run properly because it can't find some of these resources then this should fix it.